# How to split comma delimited data and create a list from the data in python?

Tags: python, list

I am trying to create a function that takes in two dates in YYYY/MM/DD format, reads through the data, and returns a list of lists containing the latitude, longitude, magnitude, and depth for the quakes between the two dates. The data is in this format:

```
Date,TimeUTC,Latitude,Longitude,Magnitude,Depth
2012/02/23,08:09:13.0,-20.984,-178.654,4.6,526
```

This is my attempt:

```
from tempBetweenDates import dateLessThan
import urllib.request

def betweenDates(date1, date2, date3): 
    """Determines if the first date is on the second or between the second and third date."""
    date_1 = date1.split('/')
    date_2 = date2.split('/')
    date_3 = date3.split('/')
    if int(date_1[0]) >= int(date_2[0]) and int(date_1[1]) >= int(date_2[1]) and int(date_1[2]) >= int(date_2[2]) and dateLessThan(int(date_1[1]), int(date_1[2]), int(date_1[0]), int(date_3[1]), int(date_3[2]), int(date_3[0])) == True:
    return True
else:
    return False

def parseEarthquakeData(date1, date2):
    page = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.choongsoo.info/teach/mcs177-sp12/projects/earthquake/earthquakeData-02-23-2012.txt")
    eqdata = page.readlines()
    dataList = []
    for line in eqdata:
        lineSplit = line.split(',')
        date = lineSplit[0]
        data = lineSplit[2:6]
        dataList = [[data] for line in eqdata if betweenDates(date, date1, date2) == True]
    return(dataList)
```

Whenever I try and run the code I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    parseEarthquakeData("2012/02/22", "2012/02/19")
  File "C:\Users\lcooper2\Desktop\Python\PROJECTS\plotEarthquakes.py", line 20, in parseEarthquakeData
    lineSplit = line.split(',')
TypeError: Type str doesn't support the buffer API
```

Any tips on how to avoid this error?

Comment: holy crud do you ever need to discover the `datetime` module! :)

Comment: avoid using if (betweenDates(date, date1, date2) == True) instead use
if (betweenDates(date, date1, date2))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python 3.X, `urllib.response.readlines` returns a byte string, and python 3 supposedly being more type safe and encoding friendly doesn't support all different encoding string within methods.

So your split method is actually been called on a byte string which expects a byte rather than a string.

So either you convert the data back to string

```
lineSplit = str(lineSplit )
```

or pass a byte string delimiter

`lineSplit = line.split(b',')`

Answer (score 1):

You can actually do something kind of cool with this! If you pipe your response from the `urllib.request.urlopen` call through `csv.DictReader`, you can eliminate a lot of your splitting and assigning.

```
import csv
import datetime
import urllib.request

page = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.choongsoo.info/teach/mcs177-sp12/projects/earthquake/earthquakeData-02-23-2012.txt")
reader = csv.DictReader((line.decode() for line in page), delimiter=',')

for line in reader:
    # each line looks like:
    # {'Longitude': '-178.654', 'Date': '2012/02/23',
    #  'Depth': '526', 'Magnitude': '4.6', 'Latitude': '-20.984',
    #  'TimeUTC': '08:09:13.0'}
    # so you can use it like a dictionary!
    date = datetime.datetime.strptime(line['Date'], "%Y/%m/%d")
    # datetime objects like this aren't naive like numbers, so you can do:
    # datetime.datetime(year=2012, month=2, day=23) < datetime.datetime(year=2012, month=2, day=24)
    # and expect it to return True every time. This will massively simplify your
    # betweenDates function.
```

The cause of the error in your traceback is that `urllib.request.urlopen` gives you an `HTTPResponse` object. That's an iterator that gives you `bytes` objects, not `string` objects. Calling `bytes.decode()` turns them into strings, so you can do stringy things with them like splitting them.

If you change to using these `datetime` objects, your `betweenDates` function becomes:

```
def between_dates(date1, date2, date3):
    return date2 <= date1 < date3
```

Comment: Is there something wrong with my answer? I'd love to correct it if that's the cause of the downvote.

Comment: NMDV, but I'm not sure about the line-by-line decoding.  Conceptually, I'm not sure lines are even *defined* until the document is decoded-- that the separations work is more a happy coincidence than anything else.  Why not simply decode and then iterate over the result of splitlines?

Comment: @DSM (at least in Python3) `urllib.request.urlopen` returns an `HTTPResponse` object, which is an iterable of `bytes` objects, each one needing to be decoded. You're saying that it might be safer to do `reader = csv.DictReader(page.read().decode().splitlines())`? I could believe that